# Ionic app: Integrate Google login with existing backend

Tags: ionic-framework, facebook-login, google-signin

I am following this [tutorial](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework) to create a google login for my Ionic app. I already have a email/pass login set in place and I wish to add google login to this system. I followed the instructions except for the logout and services part which is where it gets tricky because I already have some code for these in place for my email/pass login.

As of now clicking the login button on the login screen does nothing.

And I have the same problem for the [facebook](https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/native-facebook-login-with-ionic-framework) version of this article.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have the same problem and i follow a different path. First of all you must read https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/using-oauth-2-0-service-ionicframework/ . This link has important information about Google Developer Console. There you must "register" your ionic app and get your clientId and clientSecret. For my implementation cordovaOauth is required but it comes with ngCordova.

So the code that works for me is:

//view

```
 <button ng-click="googleLogin()" class="button button-block button-stable">
      Sign In
 </button>
```

//controller

//note that you take clientId from Google Developer Console

```
.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$cordovaOauth',    
'$http','$location','$rootScope','$state','$window','$ionicLoading',   
 function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $http, $location, 
 $rootScope,$state,$window,$ionicLoading){

  $scope.googleLogin = function(){
  $cordovaOauth.google(clientId,         


 ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",

   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"]).
  then(function(result){

  var accessToken;

  accessToken = JSON.stringify(result);


  $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Loading',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
  });
  $http({method:"GET", url:"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token="+result.access_token}).
  success(function(response){
          var param = {
            provider: 'google',
              google: {
                            uid: response["id"],
                            provider: 'google',
                            first_name: response["name"]["givenName"],
                            last_name: response["name"]["familyName"],
                            email: response.emails[0]["value"],
                            image: response.image.url
                        }
            };


            //alert("get method");

            first_name  = response["name"]["givenName"];
            email =response.emails[0]["value"];

            $scope.first_name = first_name;
            $scope.email = email;


            $ionicLoading.hide();

            $location.url('/app/viewyouwanttoredirect');

  }, function(error) {
     alert("App can't get your info: " +error);
     });


}, function(error){
   alert("Authentication error!Please try again!" +error);
   });
}

}])
```

Update:
If you have problems with oauth like "Could not find InAppBrowser plugin",
in ng-cordova.js replace all the occurrences of org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser with cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. This will solve the problem. Of course you need to have in index.html:

```
<script src="yourpath/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

You say that you don't want ngCordovaOAuth solutions but glogin comes with pain. So i post my answer and i hope to help you but also the community.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use this one for facebook login authentication :
https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

It's simple and fast. Trust me.